# Calculate moving recency-weighted mean in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the moving recency-weighted mean finishing positions of a horse given the times (day) and finishing positions (pos) for a sequence of races in which the horse participated.  Such statistics are useful in [handicapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping).

Currently, I am using a "loop-inside-a-loop" approach.  Is there a faster or more elegant R-language approach to this problem?

```
#
# Test data
#

day <- c(0, 6, 10, 17, 21, 26, 29, 31, 34, 38, 41, 47, 48, 51, 61)
pos <- c(3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6)
testdata <- data.frame(id = 1, day = day, pos = pos, wt.pos = NA)

#
# No weight is given to observations earlier than cutoff
#

cutoff <- 30

#
# Rolling recency-weighted mean (wt.pos)
#

for(i in 2:nrow(testdata)) {
  wt <- numeric(i-1)
  for(j in 1:(i-1))
    wt[j] <- max(0, cutoff - day[i] + day[j] + 1)
    if (sum(wt) > 0)
      testdata$wt.pos[i] <- sum(pos[1:j] * wt) / sum(wt)
}

> testdata

   id day pos   wt.pos
1   1   0   3       NA
2   1   6   5 3.000000
3   1  10   6 4.125000
4   1  17   1 4.931034
5   1  21   1 3.520548
6   1  26   3 2.632911
7   1  29   4 2.652174
8   1  31   1 2.954128
9   1  34   2 2.436975
10  1  38   2 2.226891
11  1  41   2 2.119048
12  1  47   6 2.137615
13  1  48   4 3.030534
14  1  51   5 3.303704
15  1  61   6 4.075000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for

```
# Calculate `wt` for all values of `i` in one go
wt <- lapply(2:nrow(testdata), function(i)
    pmax(0, cutoff - day[i] + day[1:(i-1)] + 1))

# Fill in the column
testdata$wt.pos[-1] <- mapply(
    function(i, w) if(sum(w) > 0) sum(pos[1:i]*w)/sum(w) else NA,
    1:(nrow(testdata)-1), wt)
```

Note that by calculating the second argument to `max` for all values of `j` at the same time we have vectorized the computation, which improves the speed by many orders of magnitude.

I found no easy way to vectorize the outer loop and the `if` case though (apart from rewriting it in C which seems like overkill), but `lapply`, `mapply` and similar are still faster than `for` loops.

Comment: You are confusing `numeric` with `as.numeric` in your note

Comment: When applied to a data frame consisting of 5,000 duplicates of 'testdata', this solution is about 20% faster than one using the loop-inside-a-loop approach.  There appears to be hardly any difference between using mapply and retaining the outer 'for' loop, however.

Comment: Really? That's odd, but then again R is a bit unpredictable when it comes to computation speed, so the best way is to always verify it like you did. Vectorizations is however always better than looping through since you do all the work in underlying C or fortran code. Maybe an batch calculating `wt` like I did but keeping the outer `for` loop is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This version demonstrates how to calculate moving recency-weighted means for 1 or more variables (e.g., finishing position, speed rating, etc.) and 1 or more subjects (horses).

```
library(plyr)

day <- c(0, 6, 10, 17, 21, 26, 29, 31, 34, 38, 41, 47, 48, 51, 61)
pos <- c(3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6)
dis <- 100 + 0.5 * (pos - 1)
testdata1 <- data.frame(id = 1, day = day, pos = pos, dis = dis)
day <- c(0, 4, 7, 14, 22, 23, 31, 38, 42, 47, 52, 59, 68, 69, 79)
pos <- c(1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2)
dis <- 100 + 0.5 * (pos - 1)
testdata2 <- data.frame(id = 2, day = day, pos = pos, dis = dis)
testdata <- rbind(testdata1, testdata2)

# Moving recency-weighted mean
rollmean <- function(day, obs, cutoff = 90) {
  obs <- as.matrix(obs)
  wt <- lapply(2:nrow(obs), function(i)
    pmax(0, cutoff - day[i] + day[1:(i-1)] + 1))
  wt.obs <- lapply(1:(nrow(obs)-1), FUN =
    function(i)
      if(sum(wt[[i]]) > 0) {
        apply(obs[1:i, , drop = F] * wt[[i]], 2, sum) / sum(wt[[i]])
      } else {
        rep(NA, ncol(obs))
      }
  )
  answer <- rbind(rep(NA, ncol(obs)), do.call(rbind, wt.obs))
  if (!is.null(dimnames(answer)))
    dimnames(answer)[[2]] <- paste("wt", dimnames(answer)[[2]], sep = ".")
  return(answer)
}

x <- dlply(testdata, .(id), .fun =
  function(DF) rollmean(DF$day, DF[, c("pos", "dis"), drop = F])
)
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
```